# Checking if multiple entries exist in SQL, delet them and add a new one

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have table with column `RowId`, `PersonId`, `ActivityTypeId`, `GroupId`, I select above column and it works fine.

**Bit of above table data**
Above data can have data like, same `` `PersonId `` can have multiple `activityTypeId` and activityTypeId have `GroupId`. Something like this

```
RowId  PersonId ActivityTypeId GroupId
1       20          1             2
2       20          2             2
3       20          7             8
```

Now my problem is, If for particular `PersonId`, there are more than 3 entries in same group. I wish to delete all entries of that person while selecting and add a new one manually. Can this be done in Store Procedure?

Any help will be appreciated.

Apologies, if Title doesnt make sense.

Comment: Is it SqlServer? Yes, it can do in a stored procedure, if i understood your problem, you must only delete and insert.

Comment: Yes, its SQL Server but i am confused on ````how to go about this````. Needs grouping, counting , deleting and then inserting in  suppose

Comment: Maybe something like this will be useful: **CREATE PROCEDURE my_sp
AS
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE my_field = X
INSERT INTO my_table(...) VALUES(...)**.

Comment: Are you checking a known, single personId, or you are after something that checks all personIds in the table? How are the fields in the new record that you are inserted determined from the rows you are deleting?

Comment: Mikeb: i am checking all personId

Answer (score 1):

A stored procedure would be the way to go since you are making multiple calls to different tables.

To be clear, you are trying to delete all the entries based on a specific `PersonID` and then add one from a `SELECT` statement? That can be done with the following syntax:

```
CREATE PROC my_sp 
@deletedID int, -- This is the ID of the person you are trying to delete
@insertedID int -- This is the ID of the person you are trying to add
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON -- This will ensure your select statement is not interefered

DELETE FROM Table WHERE PersonID = @deletedID

INSERT INTO Table
SELECT *
FROM Table2
WHERE PersonID = @insertedID
END
```

To call this stored procedure simply use the `EXECUTE` statement with parameters:
`EXEC my_sp 0123, 5555` Where 0123 is the ID of the deleted person and 5555 is the added one.

If you wanted to manually pass data to `INSERT INTO` instead of using the `SELECT` statement then you'll have to add more parameters and use

```
INSERT INTO Table
VALUES(@param1, @param2, @param3, ... etc)
```

Here's a link on using `INSERT INTO` which may help as well: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp